# How can I politely request that an authority figure respected protocol?

Tags: communication, internship, policy

I am in a postgraduate program, part of which is to do an internship at an organization or school recommended by the program, mostly by observing a class or by shadowing a professor at his job.

There is a requirement of a two-week internship. After that the school or organization is supposed to sign a form that the student has, in fact, fulfilled their internship obligation.

I have already started my internship in one of the locations but I have only gone twice. I am supposed to go at least eight more times.

I am in weekly contact with the person I'm "shadowing", about the day and time of my internship.

**Problem:**

This program is, as it turned out, a cash cow for the specific University and some of the faculty. There are way too many students and not enough places to intern so I assume this is why some professors/schools are willing to say that the student has completed their ten-day internship requirement even if they haven't. The director of the program knows about it and is aware or even encourages that it be done this way.

During the last communication I had with the professor I'm shadowing, she asked me to bring the form so that "you finish up slowly".

I have a feeling she'll say something like "There is a huge waiting list..." and that I can't do the ten days but she'll sign the form anyway.

If this happens, I would like to stand my ground and ask that I do the full ten days as required, even if it means doing it at random days and times or stretching it until I'm done with the program itself.

My main argument is that I am there to learn and I can't learn much by doing a three-day internship. I'm sure she knows but I still want to be able to kindly demand that she respected protocol so that I gain as much experience as I can in the field. I'm paying them anyway. They aren't paying me.

How can I best achieve my goal, if she insists on the waiting list and tries to rush me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72966/discussion-between-tychos-nose-and-anne-daunted).

Comment: I think there is a really nice question about over enrolled activities and Professors signing off on things you didn't do and not having access to the things you want, but it is buried in there and needs some pruning/editing to help us understand the question.

Comment: @StrongBad How can I improve it?